# How can I display data from custom post type marked as ‘featured post’ within a page template?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to achieve the following: 
I have a custom post type called ‘album’. I am using the Featured Post plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-post/) to select one of the albums. I want to display some data from that album in the sidebar of a page template.

At the moment the code I’m using is not returning anything:

```
<div class="left-column">
    <?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'album')); ?>
    <?php query_posts($query_string . "&featured = yes"); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h3>Latest Release</h3>
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'post-thumbnail'); ?>
        <div class="purchase">
            <h3>Purchase now</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_field('itunes_link')?>" target="_blank">
                         <img src="http://localhost:8888/rezzonator/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/itunes.png">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_field('paypal_link')?>" target="_blank">
                         <img src="http://localhost:8888/rezzonator/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/paypal.png">
                    </a>
                 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Can somebody help? I’m fairly new to PHP coding…

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by removing:

```
    <?php query_posts($query_string . "&featured = yes"); ?>
```

Editing the first line:

```
    <?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'album', 'showposts' => 1)); ?>
```

And adding this at the end:

```
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```